# Is it possible that a write in a Java socket throw without a simultaneous read throwing?

Tags: java, sockets, exception

Let's says I have two threads, one for reading and one for sending; if a write fails, will the read operation in the other thread always fail too?

I think there is at least one case where this will not be the case (InterruptedIOException if sending thread is interrupted), but is there any other? If so, are some of those cases related to network problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is if you have shutdown your socket for writing. You can't write but you can still read.

Comment: In my case, that would be a bug in the application, so if this is the only other case, then it can be ignored.

Comment: I didn't say it was the only other case ;-)

Comment: Chosing this as the answer, as it does gives a case where the write throw without the read failing.

Answer (score 0):

When a Socket is closed at the other end, you can fail to write (as the data has no where to go) but there might be unread data which you should still be able to read.

If you get a timeout on the read, you may want to close socket and kill any write. e.g. if the other end has locked up. If you don't do this the writing thread could block forever waiting to write a socket which has timed out (and may be forever)

Comment: Beccause the other is locked up and doesn't read anything, thus the TCP window is always zero. This is actually quite easy (as opposed to many other scenarios) to reproduce, just suspend the reading program - e.g. hit ctrl-Z to stop the program if it's on a *nix.

Comment: Actually we already handle timeout on read, so this side of things is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it really depends on your situation.  Probably the most common situation is your connection closing, meaning both reading and writing would fail.  However, it's not necessarily true.  You may have some weird firewall setting which allows you to read but not write.

My advice to you is to program each thread separtely rather than think up every possible scenario.  If you try to read and you can't, what happens?  If you try to write in the other thread and can't, what happens?  If it's so important that both threads can read and write, design some fallback mechanism that stops the other thread if the current thread is having trouble in some way (and if the other thread is still active of course).

Comment: Actually, I want to know if there is cases where a write failing warrants to close the reading side too, instead of waiting for it to fail.

Comment: @penpen, only if an error write means you want to discard any unread data.  I can't think of a good reason to do this.

Comment: I was not really clear: what interest me is the cases (if any) where I ends up with a failure on a write, with the read side still being blocked. In this case, I want to close and restart to be in a consistent state. If an exception on write always lead to an event on read, then indeed I just have to let things be handled separately.

Comment: Hard to say.  If your internet connection abruptly closes, windows has no qualms with throwing exceptions whenever you attempt to read or write from a socket, however that isn't the same thing as you described.  My point was that it's better to assume the case could happen and prepare for that scenario rather than see if that could ever be possible and code accordingly.

Comment: If you get a write exception, it will almost certainly be a connection reset, which will also cause the read to throw, and in any case indicates that the connection is hosed so you must close it anyway. In fact I can't think of a write exception doesn't mean that. I don't think the situation you describe can actually occur.

Comment: Murphy's Law is king when it comes to exceptions.  General rule of thumb, prepare for expected cases but also prepare for unexpected cases.  To do otherwise is just folly.